# Block ALL internet connection except localhost/127.0.0.1 - Windows 10

Tags: networking, localhost, blocking

Is there a way to fully block all internet connections except for localhost connections? I want to test localhost projects on my PS4 without the PS4 being connected to the actual internet, I just need the localhost connection on the PS4, that's all.

My operating system is Windows 10.

Setup: A Ethernet cable is connected from my PS4 to my PC. The WiFi is shared with the Ethernet adapter.

Comment: To block all Internet connection except localhost, unplug your Ethernet cable and turn off your Wi-Fi.  If that’s not what you mean, please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  Please do not respond in comments.

Comment: @Scott That blocks localhost aswell.

Comment: If it does, your computer is broken. ``localhost`` is just that — ***local**.*

Comment: @Scott I get that, but localhost is supposed to work on the PS4 without an internet connection, *or at least the internet connection being blocked*. You may have misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 0):

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 111.222.333.444 where 111.222.333.444 is your static IP.

Shut down your WiFi.  If you've got all Ethernet connections, why do you need WiFi?

Comment: The WiFi is purely for the laptop to have a internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a Loopback Adapter.

1. First uninstall all Network Bridges that you have made so far: Run **`ncpa.cpl`** in Run. Right click the **"Network Bridge"** choose **"Remove"**
2. Run **`hdwwiz.exe`** in Run → Click Next → Select **Install hardware manually selected from a list** → Click Next → Choose **"Network Adapters"** from the list → Choose **"Microsoft"** as the Manufacturer and choose **"Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter"**
3. Run **`ncpa.cpl`** in Run. Shift click the **Ethernet** connection and Shift click the new adapter labeled  **"Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter"** so you have highlighted or selected both of them. Right click one of the selected and choose **"Bridge Connections"**.

Now you have a non-internet shared connection between any Ethernet Device (your PS4) and your PC, while having a WiFi connection to your PC. You do not have to get too advanced worrying about blocking any connection to the Internet because there is not one; there is only a private connection between your PC and PS4. All localhost applications (which are native to your PC) are accessible to your PS4.